# how to write init or preload function in php which runs exactly once?

Tags: php, html

I have an html page in which I have a form.
My index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="result.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchVal" placeholder="Type here">  
    <input type="submit" value="click on me!">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a txt file which contains lots of data.
my php file which reads the txt file getdata.php is as follow

my  getdata.php

```
<?php
      $file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
      while(!feof($file))
      {
      $line = fgets($file); //utf8_encode(fgets($file));
      $piece = explode("=", $line);  
      //each line in the file is separated by = sign.like abcd=pouy.
     //So i have $piece[0] and $piece[1]
     }
     fclose($file);
    ?>
```

Now when I submit form it goes to result.php
my result.php

```
<?php include('getdata.php') ?> //getdata.php reads the file.txt
<?php
  $val=$_POST["searchVal"];
  $atoms = explode(" ", $val);
  foreach($atoms as $result) {
   // heremy code goes
   // here I need data from file.txt for which 
   // I need to include getdata.php which reads the file
  }
  ?>
```

Now when I work in this manner, the execution time becomes very high as every time I submit from I go to result.php, its load the getdata.php (everytime it reads the big file.txt).

How can I implement the same thing in such a way so that getdata.php loads for only once?

i need my index page to be html. I cannot make it with .php extensiton.Thats the restriction.

Comment: Can't you keep data in a database?

Comment: `require_once 'getData.php'`

Comment: @Flosculus or include_once

Comment: No.Its for mobile applicaion. and the file.txt is actually a dictionary.Thats why time matters so much.

Comment: I used include_once and require_once.But it does not give any result. When I submit the form it goes to result.php which includes the getdata.php. Now If I write include_once for getdata.php and submit the form again and again which results to change the url and go to result.php. In this case will require_once or include_once will work?means does url change will not have any effect on include_once or require_once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is PHP caching.  The Symfony2 way, minus the flair.

```
$lifetime = 3600;
$cache    = 'data.cache.php';

if (!file_exists($cache) || time() - filemtime($cache) > $lifetime) {
    $pieces = array();

    $file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line     = fgets($file); //utf8_encode(fgets($file));
        $pieces[] = explode("=", $line);
    }

    // Edit: moved out of loop.
    file_put_contents($cache, sprintf('<?php $pieces = %s;', var_export($pieces, true)));
} else {
    include_once($cache);
}
```

Comment: what is 'data.cache.php'?

Comment: A dynamically generated PHP script.  This code builds your data structure into an array.  If the `data.cache.php` file doesn't exist, it creates it and dumps the array build into it.  It then continues to use the array.  Next time, if the cache file does exist, it includes it, and the array is already present without needing to parse `file.txt`.

Comment: Sir my getdata.php is look like this in actual                       <?php include('trie.php') ?>
   
  <?php
       use PHPTrie\Trie;
    $trie = new Trie(); 
       $file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
          while(!feof($file))
    {
  $line = fgets($file); 
         $pieces = explode("=;", $line);
         $trie->add($pieces[0],$pieces[1]);
   }
         fclose($file);
   
  ?>                                                   Where trie is data strcture to store file data. How to make the cache in this sense?

Comment: The most time consuming part of your bootstrap is the IO of reading the file.  The time assembling the `Trie` by iterating and calling `->add` is negligible.  But benchmark it to be sure.

Comment: Sir I tried to implement your given code with my getdata.php.But its showing syntax error. Sir Can you please rewrite your answer with this getdata.php `<?php include('trie.php') ?> <?php use PHPTrie\Trie; $trie = new Trie(); $file = fopen("file.txt", "r"); while(!feof($file)) { $line = fgets($file); $pieces = explode("=;", $line); $trie->add($pieces[0],$pieces[1]); } fclose($file); ?> `